# Scala parameters for access modifiers?

Tags: scala, access-modifiers

What is the difference between

```
class Test {
  private[this] val foo = 0
}
```

vs

```
class Test {
  private val foo = 0
}
```

What all can go inside the `[]`? Also, what should I search for when I want to look up the specs of this? I tried Googling various combinations of "scala access modifier arguments/parametrized scala access modifier" and nothing came up.

Answer (score 7):

> what should I search for when I want to look up the specs of this?

In [The Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) it is defined as "access modifier" and "access qualifier" (see BNF in §5.2).

> What is the difference between
>
> ...

> What all can go inside the []?

You can put class name, package name or `this` there. Here is a relevant quote from language specs that explains this (see §5.2 for more details):

> The modifier can be qualified with an identifier C (e.g. private[C ]) that must
>   denote a class or package enclosing the definition. Members labeled with
>   such a modifier are accessible respectively only from code inside the package
>   C or only from code inside the class C and its companion module (§5.4).
>
> An different form of qualification is private[this]. A member M marked
>   with this modifier is called object-protected; it can be accessed only from
>   within the object in which it is defined. That is, a selection p.M is only legal if the prefix is this or O.this, for some class O enclosing the reference. In
>   addition, the restrictions for unqualified private apply.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is private for instance class, second is for class. If you use second version you have access from another instance of Test class (it's usefull for `equals` method or similiar).

Comment: Thank you! Can you point me to somewhere where this is documented?

Comment: See "Scope of protection" at http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/packages-and-imports.html